# Havel Hakimi: Is this sequence graphical?

Tags: graph-theory

I start studying graphs and I'm not sure if I'm using this theorem correctly.

***Question is : Does there exist a graph with 5 vertices which have the following degrees: 2, 4, 4, 4, 4?***

So I use Havel Hakimi to solve this question
I start from 4442 then 3331 then 331 then 220 then 1,1,-1
Then once I'm at 1,1,-1 we can say that the graph of the question does not exist since graph with degrees 1,1,-1 does not exist.
Am I right?

Could you help ?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this one is to observe that the complementary graph has to have four vertices of degree zero, and one vertex of degree two, which is absurd.

Answer (score 3):

Even without the use of a theorem, with five vertices a vertex of degree four must be adjacent to all other vertices.  In particular, all four of the degree-four vertices must be adjacent to the degree-2 vertex.  This is however a contradiction as the degree-2 vertex could only have been adjacent to two of the degree-four vertices and not all four of them.

Answer (score 2):

This simple graph does not exist, which you can also verify with the [Erdős–Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem), however your application of Havel-Hakimi doesn't seem to be completely correct.

We start with $(4,4,4,4,2)$, remove the first entry $d_1=4$ and reduce the next $d_1=4$ entries by $1$ to get $(3,3,3,1)$.

Now we reset the input as $(3,3,3,1)$, remove the first entry $d_1=3$ and reduce the next $d_1=3$ entries by $1$ to get $(2,2,0)$.

Again we reset the input as $(2,2,0)$, remove the first entry $d_1=2$ and reduce the next $d_1=2$ entries by $1$ to get $(1,-1)$.

The sequence $(1,-1)$ obviously isn't graphical so the original sequence $(4,4,4,4,2)$ can't be graphical.

Note that we could have stopped once we reached $(2,2,0)$ since this sequence clearly isn't graphical: there is no graph on 3 vertices such that one vertex has degree $0$ and such that the other two vertices have degree $2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is simple this sequence is not graphical but if $G$ is not simple this sequence is graphical , it's a $C_{5}$ and four vertices of the $C_{5}$ have a loop which counts as $2$ in the degree counting so we have all the degrees of those four vertices is 4 and the degree with the vertex with no loop is 2 which is exactly the sequence $(4,4,4,4,2)$.